# neo4j random nodes output

Tags: random, neo4j, match

I have a campaign node which has a relationship with Picture node.

I'm trying to get , in each campaign that the query finds , a random picture which connected to it.

I managed to get a random picture to a single campaign, but if I want to each campaign a connected picture output, I'm having trouble to do it.

This is an example to get a single picture to within a campaign.

```
MATCH (campaign:Campaign)-[]-(picture:Picture) where  
campaign.id="1429184083571" or campaign.id='1429182615443'
WITH picture, rand() AS r,campaign
ORDER BY r
RETURN campaign,picture
limit 1
```

How can i get an output for each campaign a connected random picture ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (campaign:Campaign)-[]-(picture:Picture)
with campaign, collect(picture) as pictures
RETURN campaign,pictures[toInt(rand()*size(pictures))]
```